# Indexes 2d array to 1d

Tags: c, arrays

I want to transform 2d array to 1d. I put the most important part of my code.

```
int mask[3][3] = {{0, -1, 0}, {-1, 4, -1}, {0, -1, 0}}; 

for (i = 1; i < rows - 1; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j < cols - 1;j++) {
        int s;
            s = mask[0][0] * image[i-1][j-1]
                + mask[0][1] * image[i-1][j]
                + mask[0][2] * image[i-1][j+1]

                + mask[1][0] * image[i][j-1]
                + mask[1][1] * image[i][j]
                + mask[1][2] * image[i][j+1]

                + mask[2][0] * image[i+1][j-1]
                + mask[2][1] * image[i+1][j]
                + mask[2][2] * image[i+1][j+1];
    }
}
```

my 1d array

```
for (k = rows + 1; k < (cols * rows) / 2; k++) {
  int s;
          s =  0 * image_in[k-rows-1]
          - 1 * image_in[k-rows]  
          + 0 * image_in[k-rows+1]

          - 1 * image_in[k-1]
          + 4 * image_in[k]
          - 1 * image_in[k+1]

          + 0 * image_in[k+rows-1]
          - 1 * image_in[k+rows]
          + 0 * image_in[k+rows+1];
}
```

That should be the same but I don't know if I correctly doing transformations. Can someone tell me if that is ok?

Comment: Are you getting the correct output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Why do you want to get away with the 2D array? You think that 2D array dimensions must be constant? Well, in that case I have good news for you: You are wrong. This code should work perfectly:

```
int width = ..., height = ...;
//Create a 2D array on the heap with dynamic sizes:
int (*image_in)[width] = malloc(height * sizeof(*image_in));

//initialize the array
for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        image_in[i][j] = ...;
    }
}
```

You see, apart from the somewhat cryptic declaration of the array pointer, the indexing remains exactly the same as with an automatic 2D array on the stack.

---

Within your given loop, you want to address the cells relative to the center cell. This is easiest done by actually addressing relative to that cell:

```
for (i = 1; i < rows - 1; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j < cols - 1;j++) {
        int* center = &image_in[i][j];
        int s = mask[0][0] * center[-width - 1]
                + mask[0][1] * center[-width]
                + mask[0][2] * center[-width + 1]

                + mask[1][0] * center[-1]
                + mask[1][1] * center[0]
                + mask[1][2] * center[1]

                + mask[2][0] * center[width - 1]
                + mask[2][1] * center[width]
                + mask[2][2] * center[width + 1];
    }
}
```

This works because the 2D array has the same memory layout as your 1D array (this is guaranteed by the C standard).

---

The edge handling in a 1D loop is always wrong: It will execute the body of the loop for the first and last cells of each line. *This cannot be fixed without introducing some `if()` statements into the loop which will significantly slow things down.*

This may be ignored if the consequences are proven to be irrelevant (you still need to exclude the first and last lines plus a cell). However, the edge handling is much easier if you stick to a 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

If the first part of your code gives you expected result, then you can do the same with 1d array this way :

```
for (i = 1; i < rows - 1; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j < cols - 1;j++) {
        int s;
            s = mask[0][0] * image_in[i-1+rows*(j-1)]
                + mask[0][1] * image_in[i-1+rows*j]
                + mask[0][2] * image_in[i-1+rows*(j+1)]

                + mask[1][0] * image_in[i+rows*(j-1)]
                + mask[1][1] * image_in[i+rows*j]
                + mask[1][2] * image_in[i+rows*(j+1)]

                + mask[2][0] * image_in[i+1+rows*(j-1)]
                + mask[2][1] * image_in[i+1+rows*j]
                + mask[2][2] * image_in[i+1+rows*(j+1)];
    }
}
```

This way, if you are good with 2d arrays, you can do the same without error with 1d array as if they were 2d.